# Changing image label dynamically causes entire window to grow

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make my UI (which does other things ordinarily, this is the barebones version) update an image label from a web resource. When you press the button, the entire window grows instead of the image being replaced. I thought that my call to pack would take care of this, but apparently not.

Thanks for the input!

```
from Tkinter import *
import base64
import urllib2    

BTNTEXT_NEW_COMIC = "New Comic"    

def get_random_xkcd():
    COMIC_PREFIX = 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/'
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://c.xkcd.com/random/comic/')
    html = response.read()
    if COMIC_PREFIX in html:
        index = html.find(COMIC_PREFIX)
        substring = html[index:]
        endquote = substring.find("\"")
        url = substring[:endquote]
        return url
    else:
        return    

class LoggerWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global frame 
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()    

        self.newcomic_button = Button(frame, text=BTNTEXT_NEW_COMIC, command=self.new_xkcd)
        self.newcomic_button.pack(side=LEFT)    

        self.new_xkcd()    

    def new_xkcd(self):
        global frame
        url = get_random_xkcd()
        print url
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        raw_data = u.read()
        u.close()
        b64_data = base64.encodestring(raw_data)
        self.xkcd_image = PhotoImage(data=b64_data)
        self.xkcd_label = Label(image=self.xkcd_image)
        self.xkcd_label.pack()    


root = Tk()
app = LoggerWindow(root)    

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call `self.xkcd_label.configure(image=self.xkcd_image)` instead of creating a new image like you do. If that doesn't work, try calling `self.xkcd_label.pack_forget()` to remove the label before repacking it.

Comment: Bingo! Configure was the route, I didn't even try pack_forget.

Comment: Calling `pack_forget` only removes it from view. It is still taking up memory.

Comment: Good point. I suggested `pack_forget` to remove it from the window, which would have solved the problem described. I suppose `destroy()` would be the best way to remove it from memory.